# How to Get Order_id and Order_amount from Magento2?

Tags: magento2

How to Get Order_id and Order_amount from Magento2 and pass these value to a outside of my magento store site?

Comment: At which point/case you are looking for the order_id and order_amount? Explain your question...

Comment: after clicking place order button

Answer (score 0):

You must have to first create **events.xml** file in *etc* folder to your module.

> Company/Ordertool/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="order_id_sales_after" instance="Company\Ordertool\Observer\OrderComplete" />
    </event>
</config>
```

By this observer you get the **Increment Id** instead **Order Id** as Order Id is only available after successfully order completion.

> Comapny/Ordertool/Observer/OrderComplete

```
namespace Company\Ordertool\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderComplete implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getIncrementId(); // get order id
        $orderGrandTotal = $order->getGrandTotal(); // get order total
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For get order id at the time of place order button click, you need to use a **`sales_order_save_after`** event and observer class files as below:

> etc\events.xml => **Event declaration**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">  
    <event name="sales_order_save_after"> <!-- checkout_onepage_controller_success_action--> 
        <observer name="save_request_quote_accept_pay_order" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ModuleOrderSave" />
    </event>   
</config>
```

> Observer/ModuleOrderSave.php => **Event observer class**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class ModuleOrderSave implements ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @param $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getEntityId(); //Order entity id
        $orderIncrementalId = $order->getIncrementId(); //Order incrementalId/orderid
        $orderGrandTotal = $order->getGrandTotal(); // order total


    }
}
```

By use of above code you can have Order id and order total amount and all other order information.

> After that you can use **`curl`** in the same class
>   **`ModuleOrderSave`** to pass these values to outside of your magento store site.

let me know if you need any other help.